# C++ Пример использования деструктора

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, деструктор

Если я создаю обьект класса:

```
Object* object = new Object();
```

и дальше вызываю

```
delete object;
```

объект удаляется. В класса Object нету деструктора. В чем смысл деструкторов? Где их нужно применять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе нет *определенного вами* деструктора. Значит, есть деструктор, сгенерированный компилятором - возможно, даже ничего не делающий.

Смысл деструктора - выполнение некоторых действий, которые нужно сделать при уничтожении объекта. Например, если объект связан с файлом - закрыть файл. Если выделялась какая-то память - освободить ее. Словом, в основном "положь, где взял" - некоторые действия по прибиранию за собой.

Применять их *обычно* самостоятельно не нужно. Для того он и пишется, чтобы быть вызванным **автоматически**, когда переменная выходит за пределы области видимости или когда динамически созданный объект уничтожается с помощью `delete`.